# Permisos al momento de adjuntar archivos HTML

Tags: html, html5, archivo, upload, fileupload

vengo con una duda.
Todos saben que para adjuntar un archivo se utiliza

```
<input type="file" name="fileupload"value="fileupload" id="fileupload">
```

Y se abre la ventana para seleccionar el archivo, pero se puede denegar o controlador que se pueda eliminar o copiar un archivo desde esa ventana?
Osea que solo puedas seleccionarlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

No hay forma de evitar el menú contextual en el dialogo de selección de ficheros, ya que es algo que no forma parte de tu sitio web, y por lo tanto no tienes control sobre él.

Solo podrías evitar el menú contextual dentro de tu sitio web.